# How to get all options from Getopt Long without specifc knowledge of the params?

Tags: perl

I need a simple script that echos ALL options and values given (and I have no idea what the potential options are going to be).  I've experimented with things like this:

```
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptionsFromArray);

my %options;

my @opt_spec = qw(a:s b:s c:s d:s e:s f:s g:s h:s i:s j:s k:s l:s m:s n:s o:s p:s r:s q:s r:s s:s t:s u:s v:s w:s x:s y:s z:s);

Getopt::Long::GetOptions(\%options, @opt_spec);
```

but I'm still having to specify all possible options - is there a way to get all the key/value pairs without knowing ahead of time what I'll be receiving as options?

Answer (score 4):

`Getopt::Long` supports much more than just key-value pairs: negatable options, options with multiple or hash values, incrementing options, single character and bundled options. Without giving exact scheme `Getopt::Long` just can't guess what exact abilities of module you'd want to use, so it don't seems like it is the tool for this task.

You might want [`Getopt::Whatever`](http://p3rl.org/Getopt%3a%3aWhatever) instead.

Answer (score 2):

You do need a spec. If you didn't have a spec, there would be no way to know that

```
-a=-b -c -d -e -f g --h -- -i -j
```

should give

```
my %options = (
    'a' => '-b',
    'c' => '',
    'd' => '',
    'e' => '',
    'f' => 'g'
    'h' => '',
);
@ARGV = (
   '-i',
   '-j',
);
```

instead of

```
my %options = (
    'a' => '-b',
    'c' => '-d',
    'e' => '-f',
    'h' => '--',
    'i' => '-j'
);
@ARGV = (
    'g',
);
```

(The latter used `a=s`, `b=s`, etc.)

You could write a version of `GetOptions` that gives the `:s` spec to all names, but as long as you only have single-letter args, it would be simpler to simple use code to generate the spec.

```
my @opt_spec = map "$_:s", 'a'..'z';
```